# How to add images or icons next to a text in UIPickerView in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipickerview, swift4

I made it this far and it replies my text without a problem:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var foodLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var foodSlider: UIPickerView!

    var picker = UIPickerView()

    let foodsScroll = ["pizza \npepperoni" ,"chicken \nnuggets ","meat \nballs","hamburger \nbloody","omelette \ngrilled","ice cream \nberry"]

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 80.00
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

        let cgRect = CGRect(x: 0.00, y: 0.00, width: 400, height: 200)
        let label = UILabel(frame: cgRect)
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text = foodsScroll[row]
        label.sizeToFit()
        return label
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return foodsScroll[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        return foodsScroll.count
    }


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        foodLabel.text = foodsScroll[row]
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }

}
```

And it comes to the part where I need to add a single icon to one side of each food's name. I can't quite figure out how it's done, but I know you can use 2 simple ways of:

1. Using an extra UIView and
2. Using an UIImage.

Any alternative methods are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are the question and you are the answer Yes!! here two simple way to add your idea
 1)using an extra UIView and
 2)using an UIImage.
 3)create a card
And finally it's one here it's card. but it's same as UIView

https://github.com/aclissold/CardView